# find rows that have multiple linked rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, relational-division

I am working on my highschool project 
I want to run a query for user to search medicines using multiple categories
here is the ddl,

```
Create table medicine (
  MedId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  Vendor varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  Quantity int(11) NOT NULL,
  type text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  price int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MedId)
); 

create table category(
 CatId smallint auto_increment,
 Name varchar (20),
 primary key(CatID)
);

create table MedicineCat(
MedId int,
CatId smallint,
    foreign key (MedId) references medicine(MedId),
    foreign key (CatId) references category(CatId),
    primary key(MedId,CatId)


    );


SELECT medicinecat.MedID AS 'MedId', medicine.Name AS 'Name', medicine.price AS 'Price', medicine.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
FROM medicinecat
JOIN medicine ON medicine.MedId = medicinecat.MedId
WHERE CatId in (1,2,3);
```

What I am getting is all the medicines that has at least one of the category , I know that's because of IN clause,
what I want is to select medicine that has "all the categories" not one of the category.

Comment: MySQL and/or SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: thanks for tip sir but it doesnt really matter sql server or mysql , i am asking about dml which is same for either of the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    m.MedID AS 'MedId',
    m.Name AS 'Name',
    m.price AS 'Price',
    m.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
from medicine as m
where
    exists (
        -- to get only those having all three categories
        select 1
        from medicinecat as mc
        where mc.CatId in (1,2,3) and mc.MedID = m.MedID 
        having count(*) = 3
    )
```

If you can do some generic solution like

```
select
    m.MedID AS 'MedId',
    m.Name AS 'Name',
    m.price AS 'Price',
    m.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
from medicine as m
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from (values (1), (2), (3)) as tt(CatId)
            left outer join medicinecat as mc on mc.CatId = tt.CatId and mc.MedID = m.MedID
        where mc.CatId is null
    )
```

or

```
select
    m.MedID AS 'MedId',
    m.Name AS 'Name',
    m.price AS 'Price',
    m.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
from medicine as m
where
    exists (
        -- to get only those having all categories
        select 1
        from (values (1), (2), (3)) as tt(CatId)
            left outer join medicinecat as mc on mc.CatId = tt.CatId and mc.MedID = m.MedID
        having count(tt.CatId) = count(mc.CatId)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options  (untested)

Count of categories
    DECLARE @categoryCount int
    SET @categoryCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category WHERE catid IN (1,2,3))

```
SELECT medicine.MedID AS 'MedId', medicine.Name AS 'Name', medicine.price AS 'Price', medicine.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
FROM Medicine
WHERE @categoryCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MedicineCat WHERE MedicineCat.MedId = Medicine.MedId)
```

Group By + Having

```
SELECT medicine.MedID AS 'MedId', medicine.Name AS 'Name', medicine.price AS 'Price', medicine.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
FROM Medicine
    JOIN MedicineCat ON Medicine.MedId = MedicineCat.MedId
GROUP BY medicine.MedID, medicine.Name, medicine.price, medicine.Quantity
HAVING COUNT(*) = @categoryCount
```

Multiple Exists

```
SELECT medicine.MedID AS 'MedId', medicine.Name AS 'Name', medicine.price AS 'Price', medicine.Quantity AS 'Quantity'
FROM Medicine
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MedicineCat WHERE MedicineCat.MedId = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MedicineCat WHERE MedicineCat.MedId = 2)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MedicineCat WHERE MedicineCat.MedId = 3)
```

Comment: Well, first two solution will return incorrect results if there're some categories other than 1,2,3 in the categories and MedicineCat has combinations like 1,2,4 or 2,4,5